# Why can't I click the button from the matplotlib example code when running in PyCharm?

Tags: python, matplotlib, button, pycharm

I want to use `Button` with `from matplotlib.widgets import Button`.
But it just plots the button and I can't click it.

It is the example of button in matplotlib site but it doesn't work. My IDE is PyCharm.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

freqs = np.arange(2, 20, 3)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)
t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.001)
s = np.sin(2*np.pi*freqs[0]*t)
l, = plt.plot(t, s, lw=2)


class Index:
   ind = 0

   def next(self, event):
       self.ind += 1
       i = self.ind % len(freqs)
       ydata = np.sin(2*np.pi*freqs[i]*t)
       l.set_ydata(ydata)
       plt.draw()

   def prev(self, event):
       self.ind -= 1
       i = self.ind % len(freqs)
       ydata = np.sin(2*np.pi*freqs[i]*t)
       l.set_ydata(ydata)
       plt.draw()

callback = Index()
axprev = plt.axes([0.7, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
axnext = plt.axes([0.81, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
bnext = Button(axnext, 'Next')
bnext.on_clicked(callback.next)
bprev = Button(axprev, 'Previous')
bprev.on_clicked(callback.prev)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Seems like a PyCharm issue. The code is working fine when running from the command line.

Comment: Which IDE did you run it?

Comment: No IDE, in a terminal with bash.

Comment: Is [this](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/widgets/buttons.html) the exact code that you are running? It works for me. What solved it in my case, though, was to make sure that the `Button` objects I created were not destroyed (they will be destroyed if they go out of scope). If I let them go out of scope and be destroyed, they will still be visible, but nothing will happen when I hover the mouse over them or click them.

Comment: I used a separate function to generate the contents of the figure, including the buttons; hence they went out of scope when the function returned.